# Оптимизация SQL запроса

Tags: mysqli, оптимизация, sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть простой запрос:

```
SELECT 
            ppv.id,
            ppv.property_id,
            ppv.value_id,
            ppv.text,
            p.edit_price,
            p.title,
            p.type,
            p.view,
            p.default,
            p.prefix,
            p.suffix
FROM vqbfa_properties AS p
LEFT JOIN vqbfa_product_properties_values AS ppv 
ON ppv.property_id=p.id
WHERE p.published=1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.ordering;
```

его EXPLAIN - http://clip2net.com/s/i7vF6C
профилирование - http://clip2net.com/s/i7vGaq

как видите его выполнение занимает 244.3 ms
Не могу понять почему выполняется столь продолжительное время.
Соответствующие индексы и связи прописаны.

Comment: а сколько данных возвращается? там же отправка данных занимает это время. может там пару тысяч строк...  
upd а ну вот план посмотрел, данных много, вот и медленно. вы уверены что вам нужны все?

Comment: Да, данных там много, в таблице связей около 180 тысяч строк, при запросе обходит 6 с копейками тысяч. На количество строк я посмотрел уже после того как написал сюда)

Думал может можно как то еще оптимизировать запрос, вдруг я чего то упустил)

Данные нужны все так, как на их основе формируется фильтр товаров.

Comment: Индексы на колонках в условии и группировках есть?

Comment: Да, имеются.

Comment: @TakT, все-таки, думается, лучше сократить выборку. разделить запрос на два: свойства - 14 записей, и значения - 6к. т.е. убрать из этого запроса `p.edit_price, p.title, p.type, p.view, p.default, p.prefix, p.suffix`, оставить только `p.id`, и в коде уже брать реквизиты свойств.  
ну а дальше вариант оптимизации - кэширование. запрос все-таки псевдостатический, изменения в значениях и тем более в свойствах не так часто происходят.